# Array values being replaced in nested foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I've got a simple function that compares an array of static values ($type) with dynamic values ($inventory) and is meant to add a value of 0 into the array if not found. The problem appears to be with the condition in the second foreach, somehow it's overwriting the values.

For example. If I return the array on the first iteration inside the if, I get the values I expect. But, if I return the array after all the loops have completed I just get 0 values for each element.

Here is the function.

```
function buildDriveInventory($inventory) {   
  $type = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16];
  $unit = "lbs";

  //create new array to hold values        
  $new_values = [];

  foreach ($type as $type_value) {
    foreach ($inventory as $product) {
      if ($type_value === $product['capacity']) {
        $new_values[$product['capacity'].$product['unit']] = $product['total'];
      } else {
        $new_values[$type_value.$unit] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return $new_values;

}
```

Here is an example of the `inventory` array, and what I need `new_values` to contain.

```
array(7) { 
  [0]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(1) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(6) 
  } 
  [1]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(2) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(1) 
  } 
  [2]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(4) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(2) 
  } 
  [3]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(6) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(4) 
  } 
  [4]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(8) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(4) 
  } 
  [5]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(10) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(2) 
  } 
  [6]=> array(3) { 
    ["capacity"]=> int(12) ["unit"]=> string(2) "lbs" ["total"]=> int(2) 
  } 
}

array(9) { 
  ["1lbs"]=> int(6) 
  ["2lbs"]=> int(1) 
  ["4lbs"]=> int(2) 
  ["6lbs"]=> int(4) 
  ["8lbs"]=> int(4) 
  ["10lbs"]=> int(2) 
  ["12lbs"]=> int(2) 
  ["14lbs"]=> int(0) 
  ["16lbs"]=> int(0)
}
```

Comment: What would be an example input (`$inventory`) and the expected output of the function in that instance?

Comment: Incomplete question. Please edit

Comment: I have added the arrays to the question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
function buildDriveInventory($inventory) 
{   
    $type = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16];
    $unit = "lbs";

    //create new array to hold values        
    $new_values = [];


    // build up defaults
    foreach ($type as $type_value) {
        $new_values[$type_value.$unit] = 0;
    }

    // overwrite with actual inventory
    foreach ($inventory as $product) {
        if (in_array($product['capacity'], $type)) {
            $new_values[$product['capacity'].$product['unit']] = $product['total'];
        }
    }

    return $new_values;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your code everything is Ok. Just use a **break** statement in your if block.

```
if ($type_value === $product['capacity']) {
     $new_values[$product['capacity'].$product['unit']] = $product['total'];
     break;
}
```

Full code is given below.

```
function buildDriveInventory($inventory) {   
  $type = [1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16];
  $unit = "lbs";

  //create new array to hold values        
  $new_values = [];

  foreach ($type as $type_value) {
    foreach ($inventory as $product) {
      if ($type_value === $product['capacity']) {
        $new_values[$product['capacity'].$product['unit']] = $product['total'];
        break;
      } else {
        $new_values[$type_value.$unit] = 0;
      }
    }
  }

  return $new_values;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a different style of method, you could write it like this:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/90af8955983e4ac729898f052ded19aa976a5255))

```
function buildDriveInventory($inventory,$unit='lbs',$type=[1,2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]){
    array_walk($type,function($v)use($unit,&$defaults){$defaults["$v$unit"]=0;});
    array_walk($inventory,function($a)use(&$new_inventory){$new_inventory[$a['capacity'].$a['unit']]=$a['total'];});
    return array_replace($defaults,$new_inventory);
}
$inventory=[
    ["capacity"=>1,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>6],
    ["capacity"=>2,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>1],
    ["capacity"=>4,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>2],
    ["capacity"=>6,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>4],
    ["capacity"=>8,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>4],
    ["capacity"=>10,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>2],
    ["capacity"=>12,"unit"=>"lbs","total"=>2]
];
var_export(buildDriveInventory($inventory));
```

Output:

```
array (
  '1lbs' => 6,
  '2lbs' => 1,
  '4lbs' => 2,
  '6lbs' => 4,
  '8lbs' => 4,
  '10lbs' => 2,
  '12lbs' => 2,
  '14lbs' => 0,
  '16lbs' => 0,
)
```

This allows you to write the `$unit` and `$type` data directly in the call, but the function uses default values when omitted.  Perhaps this flexibility will be useful, perhaps not.

Using `array_walk()` to generate the two prepared arrays behaves the same way as the foreach loops.

Using `array_replace()` does the work of the if-statements and avoids the need to call `in_array()` on each iteration.  In this case, `array_merge()` has the same effect, but "replace" speaks more literally/intuitively about the process being carried out.  I don't know which function performs faster, but it is likely to be nanoseconds of difference.

---

p.s. For the record, `return $new_inventory+$defaults;` worked with the same accuracy on the provided input data (and may be the fastest of all), but I didn't test it on other data sets.

Answer (score -1):

Your code will assign the second array each round of the first array, I think you want like this:

```
foreach ($inventory as $k =>$product) {
    if ($type[$k] === $product['capacity'])) {
        $new_values[$product['capacity'].$product['unit']] = $product['total'];
    } else {
        $new_values[$type[$k].$unit] = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is potentially flawed because it _assumes_ that the `$type` array and the `$inventory` array will be synchronized based on their indices rather than their type values.  More striking, this answer will not iterate the final two elements of `$type` because `$type` has 9 elements, `$inventory` has 7 subarrays, and the foreach loop is iterating on `$inventory`